# Passing more than one template type to operator<< in c++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operators

Is it possible to write the following `print` function, as is, using `operator<<`. I've some image data that may be stored in various ways, including as unsigned char. When printing I want to cast the `unsigned char` values to `int`, so it displays correctly. However, I only need to specify a type for unsigned char, so I use a default template argument otherwise.

I've used a `std::vector` for **illustrative** purposes. This will actually be for a buffer containing pixel data on which I won't be able to determine its type until runtime, so i'll always be specifying the source type `T`.

I realise I could write a specialisation for when the data type is `unsigned char`, but wondered if it was possible to combine into one generic `operator<<` function, as is possible with `print`?

```
template<typename T, typename U = T>
std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& vals)
{
    for (auto v : vals) {
        os << U{v} << ' '; // Warns on narrowing conversion.
    }

    return os;
}
```

Called using code like the following,

```
vector<unsigned char> vc{ 1, 2, 3 };
vector<int> vi{ 4, 5, 6 };

print<unsigned char, int>(vc);
print<int>(vi);
```

I tried replacing print with operator<<, but the error message suggested I was clashing with `basic_ostream`'s declaration (`template <class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT>> class basic_ostream`).

Comment: @TemplateRex
I've actually gone with the following in the function body,

`using U = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, unsigned char>::value, int, T>::type;`

and removed the template parameter. The template parameter won't then show up in the Doxygen output, plus it wasn't ever usable.

Can I surmise that there's no way of passing U explicitly to operator<< ?

Comment: You can but you need to write sth. ugly as `std.cout.operator<<<U>(myvec)` which also inhibits ADL, so I would rather avoid that.

Comment: Yuck. In that case i'm not losing anything by having a print function. Thanks for you answers.

Comment: It ended up being the following monstrosity,

`operator<< <unsigned int>(cout, dataImage);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++11, you can use a simple `std::conditional` and `std::is_same<T, unsigned char>` as a defaulted template parameter that you never need to override. This means that you can use the familiar `<<` streaming syntax

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template
<
    class T, 
    class U = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, unsigned char>::value, int, T>::type
>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> const& vals)
{
    for (auto v : vals) {
        os << U{v} << ' ';
    }

    return os;
}

int main()
{
    auto const vc = std::vector<unsigned char>{ 1, 2, 3 };
    auto const vi = std::vector<int>{ 4, 5, 6 };        

    std::cout << vc << "\n";
    std::cout << vi << "\n";
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d08e1fe3d295d775).

There are [**Boost equivalents**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html) in case you are bound to C++98.